# Should I remove a SelectionKey from SelectedSet?

Tags: java, nio

I have a question about reading from `SocketChannel`. Suppose we have something like this:

```
SelectionKey key = //;
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(128);
SocketChannel ch = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
int bytesRead = ch.read(b); //returns 128
```

So in that case I cannot know for sure if all ***available*** bytes read from the channel (because bytes read and the buffer size are the same). So do I need to remove `key` from `SelectedSet`? Or on the even if I remove, on the next event loop iteration I can retrieve the key and read all rest bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If there is more data to be read, OP_READ will fire again.